# How to restore correct window control behaviour in Gnome?

Tags: gnome, gtk, settings, pantheon, window-control

I'm having an issue on my laptop which is preventing me from changing the settings for GTK+ applications that use headerbars. Non-header bar applications are working just fine.

What happened is that I'd previously had Pantheon installed, but since upgrading, I've not been able to keep up with Pantheon releases, so I'd disabled the PPA (but kept some of the apps I was still using).

Since then, I've tried to clear all of the packages that aren't related to the apps I still use (Plank, Footnote).

However, window controls in Gnome are still working as they would in Pantheon. Changing the settings in dconf editor or Tweaks has no effect.

[image: desktop screenshot]

How can I restore normal functionality?

Resetting the gsettings value did nothing. Logging out and logging in did nothing. I'm stumped at this point.

---

Here's the latest:

- I tried resetting gsettings (remove `~/.config/dconf/*` and kill all processes immediately to prevent it from being recreated with existing settings). No avail.
- I searched for every possible GTK+ related settings file in `~/.config`, `~/.local`, and `~/.cache`. Nothing works.

Comment: What does `gsettings get org.pantheon.desktop.gala.appearance button-layout` say?

Comment: @pomsky `no such schema`

Comment: If you don't mind loosing other desktop configs, consider clearing out `~/.config` folder or at least those specific to anything GNOME or Gtk related.  Before you do that, consider creating new user and logging into GNOME session to confirm that this is a user-related issue, and not a globally altered config ( in which case you probably will have to dig through `/usr` and `/etc/` directories

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy I'm hoping someone will be able to point me in a more specific direction. Something has to be controlling the layout of the buttons at a level beyond gsettings, and that's what I need to track down.

Comment: @RolandiXor Well, there's not a lot of options from what I know. Typically, GSettings  schemas or GLib schemas (either user-specific or global in `/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/` ) are the likely culprits. There's also configs in `~/.config` or `/etc/xdg/`.  Like I mentioned, try creating new user session first to figure out if it's global or local, and then you can get to specific troubleshooting methods.

Comment: Definitely a local issue. Just tested a new account and the issue doesn't occur there. Time to poke around a little further. I'm not going to nuke my config as that would likely mess with other things.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91108/discussion-on-question-by-rolandixor-how-to-restore-correct-window-control-behav).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the answer in the most unusual of places:

It was the display manager at fault somehow. Switching from SDDM to GDM solved the problem.