# Are settings for Gnome headerbars stored separately?

Tags: gnome, settings

Related to this question: [How to restore correct window control behaviour in Gnome?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1125401/how-to-restore-correct-window-control-behaviour-in-gnome?noredirect=1#comment1863695_1125401)

I'm trying to determine if there are any settings in gsettings or elsewhere that I'm missing, since regular windows are following the gsettings value, but CSD windows are not.

Comment: My understanding of CSD is that each application that uses CSD decides how its headerbar looks. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/961161/how-do-i-disable-client-side-decoration-globally-in-gnome

Comment: @DKBose yes, but with Gnome, the application still shares certain settings with the system.